# WP8.1 RT: Databinding (remote) images slow down app

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

**Background:**

I'm working on a WP8.1/WP10 mobile app that works with a local device I have here. This local device serves json and images through an ASP.NET Web APi. My app makes web calls to get information and display the information to the user. Quite simple setup.

My process works as following: User starts the app. The app finds the 'webservice' on the network with UPNP. When it does, it exchanges a token, and we can start calling on the web service. I'm grabbing a list of objects that contain a title, subtitle and an image. Images uri are like:

```
192.168.1.x:8080/getImage/?uri=someremoteimageurihere.
```

My device will download these images and return them to the app (I need it to work this way for some other uses this device has).

In order to keep the UI fluid, I use virtualization on the list that I'm showing, and the user is able to scroll through the list without any lag. So far, so good. There is but one issue:

**My issue**

My issue is with the images in my listview template. While the UI is responsive, the phone is constantly downloading images, especially when a user is scrolling from item #300 to item #1. You'll see it downloading the images one by one from #299 all the way to #1. The problem is that the user is viewing #1 in the list, and it will take a minute or so for all the images to have downloaded, it goes from #299 to #1.

I'm wondering how I can get more control over the loading of these images. While it is downloading these images, my app seems to have little time for "other" tasks, e.g. all of the other calls to the web api seem to wait until the images on the screen have loaded (this without locking the ui thread!). So basically if I navigate to a settings flyout - the settings will only load after the batch of images have been loaded.

Is there any way for me to load these images on a single background thread? The delay for the end-user is acceptable, as long as the binding of the images doesn't get priority over any other images.

**This question is NOT about:**

- Locking up the UI thread while doing work
- Help with binding data
- Caching strategies

Thanks for your insights!

Comment: Does you webapi serve the images in the size the phone needs to display them or is it resizing them?  Resizing is slow.

Comment: No it doesn't, and I have no way of doing so (that part is third party). So yes, all images are resized on the fly which is not helping.

Answer (score 1):

Would the phasing feature fix you issue ?
Phasing is a feature of {x:Bind} that works with controls derived from ListViewBase and that incrementally processes the item template for data binding. When rendering list items, ListViewBase renders a single phase for all items in the view before moving onto the next phase. The rendering work is performed in time-sliced batches so that as the list is scrolled, the work required can be re-assessed, and not performed for items that are no longer visible.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-phase-attribute

Answer (score 1):

You should try Random data access data virtualization on your listview:

Random access data virtualization allows loading from an arbitrary point in the data set. A ListView that uses random access data virtualization, used to view a collection of a million items, can load the items 100,000 – 100,050. If the user then moves to the beginning of the list, the control loads items 1 – 50. At all times, the scroll bar's thumb indicates that the ListView contains a million items. The position of the scroll bar's thumb is relative to where the visible items are located in the collection's entire data set. This type of data virtualization can significantly reduce the memory requirements and load times for the collection. To enable it you need to write a data source class that fetches data on demand and manages a local cache and implements these interfaces.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/listview-and-gridview-data-optimization#random-access-data-virtualization

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bind directly to your downloaded images (as an ImageSource resource) instead of using the server Uri : so you have all the control you need to download these image in your own code in the background and make them available in your ViewModel as a collection of images.

You can try that code:

```
public async void GetImage(Uri url) 
{ 
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url); 
    byte[] img = response.Content.ReadAsByteArray(); 
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream(); 

    DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0)); 
    writer.WriteBytes(img); 

    await writer.StoreAsync(); 

    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(); 
    bi.SetSource(randomAccessStream);

    image1.Source = bi; 
}
```

Please mark as answered if that helps :)

Comment: I've tried this, this is not a solution to my problem though. The issue I have is that if you scroll from #1 in the listview to #300, it will download every image from 1-300, while I only need to to download the ones on screen. Your "getimage" method is just another way of setting the image source, which is not my actual problem :).

Comment: What kind of virtualization are you using for your listview ? Incremental or random access ?